# fail2ban save banned ip's after restart

Tags: linux, fail2ban

It is possible to save and use _already banned IP's in fail2ban after restart (fail2ban or the whole server)?

Answer (score 3):

As of 2016, this is actually the default. It was probably added around 2011 or 2012, though. So you have nothing to do now.

The ban database is defined in `fail2ban.conf` with two variables:

```
# Options: dbfile
# Notes.: Set the file for the fail2ban persistent data to be stored.
#         A value of ":memory:" means database is only stored in memory 
#         and data is lost when fail2ban is stopped.
#         A value of "None" disables the database.
# Values: [ None :memory: FILE ] Default: /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3
dbfile = /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3

# Options: dbpurgeage
# Notes.: Sets age at which bans should be purged from the database
# Values: [ SECONDS ] Default: 86400 (24hours)
dbpurgeage = 86400
```

To avoid the persistence, now that this is the default, edit the `fail2ban.conf` file and then change the `dbfile = <path>` with:

```
dbfile = None
```

I'm not too sure what the difference between `None` and `:memory:` is, either way, those two will prevent the IPs from being re-added to your firewall on a restart or a reboot.

Comment: As far as I can tell it was added in fail2ban 0.9.

Comment: I'm using v0.8.13 and it's already working like this (persisting banned ip)

Comment: How can one disable it?

Comment: @IvanVelichko, I updated my answer to include the two variables used by fail2ban to handle its database.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. My recomendation is to either ban for a somewhat short amount of time, or perma-ban. I configure my servers to dump a list of the perma-banned IPs to a configuration file ever 6 hours and at shutdown; then auto load that file at startup.

I have my rules setup so the perma-ban jails are very touchy, for instance 2 different invalid usernames when logging into the webmail portal will trigger it. The jails for common things like correct username/wrong password get triggered after 10 and only bans for a short time.